# How do I connect a SoftEther bridge to a server without getting an authentication error?

Tags: vpn, authentication, bridge, softether

I've been playing around with SoftEther, and I'm trying to use the VPNCMD utility to create a site to site VPN. However, when I try to get the Cascade connection up between the bridge and the server, I get a user authentication error. Which is weird, because the user doesn't even have a password set on it. These are all in VM's that have no trouble pinging each other. Here's my code on the bridge side:

```
VPN Server/BRIDGE> BridgeCreate BRIDGE /Device:eth0 /TAP:no
VPN Server/BRIDGE> CascadeCreate TestCascade /SERVER:192.168.1.12:5555 /HUB:TestHub /USERNAME:Test
VPN Server/BRIDGE> CascadeOnline TestCascade
VPN Server/BRIDGE> CascadeList
```

All of the settings are correct to what's set up on the cluster controller. However, we get an error:

```
Status | Error 9: User Authentication Failed
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Provide the username which you use for logging to VPNSERVER, that should work